# If parent li hasclass append class to child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class called "animated" to a child div only when the parent li has a class called "current". Additionally, I'm trying to remove the "animated" class if the parent li does not show the "current" class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('ul.itemwrap li').hasClass('current')) {
   $( "ul.itemwrap li" ).find( ".caption-text" ).addClass("animated"); 
    }
else { 
$( "ul.itemwrap li" ).find( ".caption-text" ).removeClass( "animated" );
    }
});
```

***problem**** 
the code works, somewhat, however, it's only adding the class to all child (.caption-text) elements as well as not removing them when the "current" class is added and removed throughout the carousel loop.

**Html***
`<ul class="itemwrap">
        <li class="current"> <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="img-description">
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-holder">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="caption-text">
                  <h1>title</h1>
                   </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li> <img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="img-description">
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-holder">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="caption-text">
                  <h1>Title</h1>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li> <img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="img-description">
          <div class="caption">
            <div class="caption-holder ">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="caption-text">
                  <h1>Title></h1>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
</ul>`

Comment: And, the problem is what exactly?  We HAVE to see your HTML and have you tell us what isn't working to have any idea what is going wrong here.  An acceptable question here on SO must have a clear description of the expected behavior and the observed behavior and include enough information for people to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Also looks like you've put this code in the document ready which will be only called once when the document is finished loading which is probably not what you want. If not, then post the entire code with the html

Comment: It is better if you create a http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right.  I should have added the html and outlined the problem.  See my revised comment. Thanks.  I'll put a jsfiddle example together if need be...

Answer (score 0):

An issue with your code is that if one `<li>` has the class `'current'`, then you're adding the class animated to all `".caption-text"` elements, not just the ones below the item with `'.current'`.

You could fix your code in a couple ways.  This way processes each `<li>` individually:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.itemwrap li').each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        var caption = item.find(".caption-text");
        if (item.hasClass('current')) {
            caption.addClass("animated");
        } else {
            caption.removeClass("animated");
        }
    });
});
```

This way uses selectors to do more of the work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // clear .animated from all captions
    $('ul.itemwrap li .caption-text').removeClass("animated");

    // put back the .animated under .current
    $('ul.itemwrap li.current .caption-text').addClass("animated");
});
```